# In gradle, can I read extra property of subproject from root project?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

In my root project, I'd like to config "apt" for all my projects like code below. But I don't know how to get package name from subproject?

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'android-apt'

    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName '?????'
        }
    }
}
```